# improved grasp of the English language than a year ago

Tags: grammar

*He showed a much improved grasp of the English language than a year ago.*

This sentence is supposed to be grammatically wrong (the usage of the phrase "than a year ago"). Can you please explain to me why?

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is wrong because *improved* is not a comparative.

> He showed a much **better** grasp of the English language than *[he showed]* a year ago.

Or

> He showed a much improved grasp of the English language **compared to/over** *what he showed* a year ago.

The *[(what) he showed]* bits *can* be omitted, and the sentence will still be grammatical, but also rather awkward as the structure would not be exactly parallel (see @Sandeep's answer); I recommend to include them

Answer (score -1):

I think the sentence is comparing two incomparable things. You can't compare **grasp** with **an year ago**. Sentence should be - **improved grasp of the English language than *he/she had* an year ago**.

Comment: @Downvoter- Reveal yourself and enlighten me.

Comment: This isn't wrong, it just isn't the root cause of OP's issue. Still, a good point to keep in mind +1

Comment: I think you might benefit by posting your answer as a question: "Is this sentence comparing two incomparable things? ... Can it (would it) be interpreted as comparing two incomparable things?"

Comment: @blgt, I disagree; it is wrong.  I can compare my grasp (today, which is implied) with my grasp a year ago.  The problem is that you don't use "than" with "improved"; as stated your own answer, it's not a comparative.  (also, it's "a year ago", not "an year ago", since the *Y* does not have a vowel sound in the word "year".)  If you want to use "improved", you should have a timespan or a starting point: something like "His grasp has improved a lot over the last year."